# Cannot Assign Value Of Type

Tags: ios, string, swift, boolean

My project is getting one build error when running my application. I'm not exactly what sure is wrong in the code here but the error is given on the line where "activity.completionWithItemsHandler" begins. Any suggestions as to what needs to be changed? Thanks for your help guys. Here's my code:

```
//
//  MemeEditorViewController.swift
//  MemeMe
//
//  Created by Humberto Aquino on 4/3/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Humberto Aquino. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

// Meme editor view. Memes can use the photo library or the camera (is       supported)
// When ready, the meme can be shared
class MemeEditorViewController: UIViewController,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

// Meme text and image
@IBOutlet weak var topTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

// Top bar
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIBarButtonItem!

// Bottom bar
@IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!

// Existing meme reference. Used only when the editor will edit an existing meme
var meme: Meme?


// MARK: -
// MARK: View life cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let existingMeme = meme {
        // Existing meme. Use self.meme
        setupTextField(existingMeme.top, textField: topTextField)
        setupTextField(existingMeme.bottom, textField: bottomTextField)
        imageView.image = existingMeme.image
        shareButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        // New meme. self.meme is not used
        setupTextField("TOP", textField: topTextField)
        setupTextField("BOTTOM", textField: bottomTextField)
        shareButton.enabled = false
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Enable the camera button if is supported by the device
    cameraButton.enabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)
    subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unsubscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: NSNotification subscriptions and selectors

func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func unsubscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }
}

func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // When a user taps inside a textfield, the default text should clear.
    textField.text = ""
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // When a user presses return, the keyboard should be dismissed
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = originalImage
        // Enable share button now that we have an image
        shareButton.enabled = true
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func cancelMeme(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func shareMeme(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //  generate a memed image
    let memedImage = generateMemedImage()

    // define an instance of the ActivityViewController
    // pass the ActivityViewController a memedImage as an activity item
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [memedImage], applicationActivities: nil)

    activity.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: String!, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [AnyObject]!, activityError: NSError!) -> Void in
        if completed {
            // Save meme and dismiss
            self.saveMeme(memedImage)
            activity.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // present the ActivityViewController
    presentViewController(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func pickAnImageFromAlbum(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    presentImagePickerOfType(.PhotoLibrary)
}

@IBAction func pickAnImageFromCamera(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    presentImagePickerOfType(.Camera)
}

// MARK: -
// MARK: Utility methods

// Setup Text filed to approximate to the "Impact" font, all caps, white with a black outline
func setupTextField(string: String, textField: UITextField) {
    let memeTextAttributes = [
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3
    ]

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: memeTextAttributes)
    textField.attributedText = attributedString
    textField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    // Text should be center-aligned
    textField.textAlignment = .Center
    textField.delegate = self
}

// Present the image picker depending on the specified sourceType
func presentImagePickerOfType(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func toolbarVisible(visible: Bool) {
    toolBar.hidden = !visible
    navigationBar.hidden = !visible
}

func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
    // hide toolbar
    toolbarVisible(false)

    // Render view to image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let memedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // show toolbar
    toolbarVisible(true)

    return memedImage
}

// Saves the meme correctly. Is the meme is new it saves a new one in the shared model
// If the meme already exists the method only updates its values
func saveMeme(memedImage: UIImage) {
    if let existingMeme = meme {
        // Meme exists. Just change its existing properties
        existingMeme.top = topTextField.text!
        existingMeme.bottom = bottomTextField.text!
        existingMeme.image = imageView.image!
        existingMeme.memedImage = memedImage
    } else {
        // New meme. Create one and add it to the sahred model
        let meme = Meme(top: topTextField.text!, bottom: bottomTextField.text!, image: imageView.image!, memedImage: memedImage)
        // Add the saved meme to the shared model
        MemeManager.sharedInstance.appendMeme(meme)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the *actual* and *exact* error message? And do you mean `activity.completionWithItemsHandler`? I see no "`itemswithcompletionhandler`". Please practice precision when asking questions on SO.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi yea my apologies, I am a beginner programmer! The error message is as what you wrote "activity.completionWithItemsHandler" Here's the full error Cannot assign value of type '(String!, Bool, [AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void' to type 'UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler?'

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi please see my update. And take note, I am a beginner. The error I made in the post was hardly anything you couldn't understand but I have no clue what you're references in your suggestion, in fact you didn't really offer a suggestion, you told me my question was wrong and down voted it. Do you actually have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I gave you my best guess considering your previous, unedited question. This was I thought obviously contingent on answers to the questions I asked you. Your expectation of a complete solution is a bit premature and somewhat unreasonable when asking others for help. I needed more information for a more specific answer.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi are you not seeing the edited version of my question?

Comment: Yes. It contains one change. But you addressed that in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you've posted so far (which is incomplete and inaccurate as of this answer and my comment to your question), I see you're specifying the completion handler closure's parameters as required (`!`) when the docs say they're optional (`?`). I'm not certain, but I believe it's not letting you assign the closure because the signature of *your* closure doesn't match `UIActivityViewController`'s expectations.

Comment: What do you mean "signature"? Again, im a newbie so please understand. What exactly needs to be taken out or added?

Comment: The signature is the pattern of parameters of a function (a closure is an anonymous function). Your closure's signature uses exclamation points to force-unwrap your parameters but the expected signature uses optional values (a question mark). Look up the property you're trying to set in the API reference docs and compare. This is a basic job a developer has to do hundreds of times a day. Giving you the exact code  teaches you nothing and your attitude above suggests you could use a lesson in research.

Comment: Here, have a look at the type it's expecting: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler Pay attention to what cones after each parameter type. Not a "`!`" in sight. Hmmm... Now what was it I said in my answer about `!`...?

Comment: As to your comment above, where you said I hadn't offered a suggestion, I trust it's clear that in fact I did. Here's another: that you didn't yet understand it doesn't mean it's not there. And another: adjust your attitude to include the fact you're asking people to take time to help you for free and if you need clarification, ask *respectfully* and be prepared for it to *take a little while* before they answer, as they may have other things to do (like a paying job or a family).